# UIToolbar reuse like inputAccessoryView

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitoolbar

Some quest!
If i have toolbar in view(bottom) and i want that he will become like input accessoryView for textview. It is possible? Or i must use animations core for this manipulation?